# pyqt5 set font for all parts in a dialog box

Tags: python

I made a dialog box with PyQt5, there are several QLabels, QLineEdits and QPushButtons, how can I set Font to all these parts? it will to many lines to set font one by one. Can I have Font settings by one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = QFont("Arial", 30)
app.setFont(f)
```

this should work

Comment: thanks! it can set default font style , also can keep some my original font settings. thanks for save my time.